# Karate Jakarta EE upgrade

Tags: java, karate, java-17

I am curious if there is a timeline on upgrading the use of Javax to Jakarta throughout the karate framework

Upgraded the karate framework on a fork and everything seems to be good.

It is my understanding that Javax is being moved from on most other projects in favor of Jakarta

Comment: as far as I know karate does not use any of the javax apis. you are welcome to raise an issue with details, better still a PR would be great

Answer (score 0):

**No (as of 08/2023)**

As far as I browse the [Karate GitHub](https://github.com/karatelabs/karate) repository, there is nothing related to planning a migration to Jakarta EE:

- Issues: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/issues?q=jakarta
- Pull requests: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/pulls?q=jakarta

Perhaps, it's time now to create an issue.